# some key missing in json from web service response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdata

Here is my code :

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    //Create an URLRequest
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"...my url ..."];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Create POST Params and add it to HTTPBody
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"p_no=%@&app_key=%@&lat=%f&lan=%f&lat_t=%f&lan_t=%ftime=%@&date=%@",phoneSaved,appKeySaved,pickUpLocLat,pickUpLocLng,pickUpDestLat,pickUpDestLng,[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now],date_String];// my params which i think are good
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Create task
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
        NSDictionary *dictVerify = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        //NSLog(@"%@",dictVerify);
        NSString *errorReturn = [dictVerify objectForKey:@"error"];
        //NSString *message = [dictVerify objectForKey:@"message"];
        if (!errorReturn) {
            NSLog(@"amazing : %@",dictVerify); // this logs the serialized data

        } else {
            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Verification"
                                                                                     message:errorReturn
                                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
            UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                             handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
            [alertController addAction:actionOk];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

the response is :

```
count = 1;
    data =     (
                {
            "base_fare" = "20.00";
            "c_no" = WB60000;
            "c_type" = 1;
            "car_type_label" = Mini;
            color = white;
            "d_id" = bZ;
            "d_type" = 1;
            "driver_type_label" = "Individual Driver";
            "f_name" = Saikat;
            "l_name" = Singh;
            status = 1;
            "waiting_time" = 8;
        }
    );
```

here only two keys are missing which are lat and lan which is below from web service :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "d_id": "bZ",
            "lat": "22.588305",
            "lan": "88.410210",
            "d_type": "1",
            "c_type": "1",
            "status": "1",
            "driver_type_label": "Individual Driver",
            "car_type_label": "Mini",
            "c_no": "WB60000",
            "color": "white",
            "f_name": "Saikat",
            "l_name": "Singh",
            "waiting_time": "8",
            "base_fare": "20.00"
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

I cannot find any issue , cause data is returning but only keys are missing , I haven't faced this kind of issue before , please help. If you need any more info please leave comment I will update the details accordingly .

Comment: i thing this is server -side problem

Comment: if possible provide url so that i can check

Comment: Probably a Server change. I find strange the way you create the HTTPBody parameters. Usually, we create a NSDictionary/NSArray and convert them into NSData (through JSONSerialization).

Comment: solved the issue , post param I am sending is wrong